# How to dynamically update fields on duplicate key with Sequelize.bulkCreate

Tags: sequelize.js

How would one implement `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = score + VALUES(score)

My pseudocode:

```
  await User.bulkCreate(
    [{...}],
  {
    updateOnDuplicate: ['score']   // This only overwrites the previous value 
  }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Sequelize source code it turns it out this is not implemented yet, so for anyone having a similar issue i used this approach:

```
const records = [{score, ...}, {score. ,,,}, ...];
await Promise.all(records.map((record) => User.create(
  record,
  {
    onDuplicate: 'UPDATE score = score + VALUES(score)'
}
))
```